# Json, PHP, and sessions

Tags: php, json, session

I would like to print a value from the following JSON in PHP.  How would I access a specific value?  Also this array is stored in a session call `forminfo`.  So I need to access the session then the specific value of `FirstName` for example.

```
Array (
    [forminfo] => stdClass Object (
        [GetProspectAsJSONResult] => [
            {
                "ProspectId": xxxxx,
                "Keycode": "Test123",
                "FirstName": "Test",
                "LastName": "Test",
                "Company": "Test",
                "Email": null 
            }
        ] 
    )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not JSON.  For the part that is JSON, `json_decode()` is what you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 0):

you should use `json_decode` on object which decodes it and returns an array. then you could for example access `Firstname` with `decodedArray['FirstName']`

Comment: I'm using a web service that returns the following info:
stdClass Object ( [GetProspectAsJSONResult] => [ { "ProspectId": xxxxx, "Keycode": "Test123", "FirstName": "Test", "LastName": "Adm1", "Company": "Test", "Email": null } ] )
If I json_decode the result above it's just blank.